# How to update in one thread and read from many?

Tags: multithreading, rust, borrow-checker

I've failed to get this code past the borrow-checker:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::{sleep, spawn};
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct State {
    count: u64,
    not_copyable: Vec<u8>,
}

fn bar(thread_num: u8, arc_state: Arc<State>) {
    let state = arc_state.clone();
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!("thread_num: {}, state.count: {}", thread_num, state.count);
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut state = State {
        count: 0,
        not_copyable: vec![],
    };
    let arc_state = Arc::new(state);

    for i in 0..2 {
        spawn(move || {
            bar(i, arc_state.clone());
        });
    }

    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(300));
        state.count += 1;
    }
}
```

I'm probably trying the wrong thing.

I want one (main) thread which can update `state` and many threads which can read `state`.

How should I do this in Rust?

---

I have read [the Rust book on shared state](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html), but that uses mutexes which seem overly complex for a single writer / multiple reader situation.

In C I would achieve this with a generous sprinkling of `_Atomic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomics are indeed a proper way, there are plenty of those in std ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html#structs). Your example needs 2 fixes.

1. Arc must be cloned *before* moving into the closure, so your loop becomes:

```rust
for i in 0..2 {
    let arc_state = arc_state.clone();
    spawn(move || { bar(i, arc_state); });
}
```

2. Using `AtomicU64` is fairly straight forward, though you need explicitly use newtype methods with specified [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html) ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53f2c7e86ebb76b1dc98f4185da8bf0a)):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::{sleep, spawn};
use std::time::Duration;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct State {
    count: AtomicU64,
    not_copyable: Vec<u8>,
}

fn bar(thread_num: u8, arc_state: Arc<State>) {
    let state = arc_state.clone();
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        println!(
            "thread_num: {}, state.count: {}",
            thread_num,
            state.count.load(Ordering::Relaxed)
        );
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let state = State {
        count: AtomicU64::new(0),
        not_copyable: vec![],
    };
    let arc_state = Arc::new(state);

    for i in 0..2 {
        let arc_state = arc_state.clone();
        spawn(move || {
            bar(i, arc_state);
        });
    }

    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(300));
        // you can't use `state` here, because it moved
        arc_state.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}
```